# VBA reference a field on form that has a dot in its name

Tags: ms-access, vba, field

I am working on an Access 2010 project, I have created a form and am using an if statement to enable/disable fields.

The code I am using is,

```
DueDate.Enabled = False
```

This is working fine apart from a combo-box called "tblJobs.Engineer" I can't rename this field but I think the problem is the dot in it as I'm getting error object required.

I have tried adding `Forms!frmJobs!` to the start but it is still getting the same error.

Comment: Yes you **can** rename the "field" (it's actually an object, not a field, but that's another issue...), and you **should** rename the "field".  Standard Access coding practice is to never use dots or spaces in table field names, and you should follow those same guidelines for objects.  It will eliminate the need to use brackets, which is a Mickey Mouse solution to fix poor coding choices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bracket the problem name so it can be recognized as one "thing".

```
[tblJobs.Engineer].Enabled = False
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got some good input already but I'm just going to clarify it a bit.

1) Don't use spaces, symbols, or punctuation in the names of your fields, tables, forms, or queries.

2) Consider renaming the controls on your form so that they are not named identical to the underlying DAO Recordset field they are bound to. This way, as shown below, you can choose to refer to the field or the control separately without any confusion to the programmer or to MS Access.

```vb
'Refer to a combo
Me.cboEngineer.Enabled = False

'Refer to a textbox
Me.txtDueDate.Enabled = False

'Refer to an underlying DAO Recordset field (early binding)
Me.Engineer = "Donald"

'Refer to an underlying DAO Recordset field (late binding)
Me!Engineer = "Donald"
```