# No longer able to use field names of underlying DAO recordset in VBA code

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

Does anybody know what the setting is to allow VBA access to the fields in the Form's underlying DAO Recordset please? I know this is possible as evidenced by the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19018261/470014

For some reason I am no longer able to use the field names of the underlying DAO recordset (which happens to be a query) in my VBA code.

So I used to be able to do

`myvalue = FieldName`

rather than

`myvalue = Me.Recordset.Fields("FieldName").Value`

I realise this probably isn't the best practice but I have a lot of legacy code working like this and now the database forms are regularly falling over so I'm faced with a massive unexpected clean up job to get it working again.

I thought I was imagining it so I restored an old copy of the database and sure enough I am able to use the fieldname on it's own but not in the latest version. The only thing I can think of that has changed is that the database got corrupted by someone inadvertently working on it in Access 2010 so I created a new database and imported all of the objects from the old one. I have checked the VBA libary references and Options and they are identical. This makes me think it must be a database setting but I have been through them all and can't see any differences.

Also Intellisense used to list the underlying fieldnames along with the regular form controls but this is no longer the case either.

Update: 
I have found that `myvalue = Me!FieldName` works but for some reason I used to be able to do `myvalue=FieldName` but that if I do that the value is always `Empty`.

Comment: Did your import work into the new database? You don't explain if this resolved your issue or not.

Comment: @enderland The import into a new database worked in that it fixed the corruption in the database. However I have only become aware of the problem with accessing the underlying fields posted above since the import.

Comment: You tagged your question access 2007 and you explain in your question that you are in 2010. Have you migrated fron 2007 to 2010 ? The only "option" I can think about is " Require Variable Declaration " in VBA tools menu. It automatically adds "option explicit" on top of your new modules. Which lead me to my next question: does it fail at compile or at runtime ?

Comment: @ThomasGrandjean I'm using Access 2007. I asked another developer to do something for me and unbeknownst to me he

Comment: @ThomasGrandjean I'm using Access 2007. I asked another developer to do something on it for me and unbeknownst to me he used Access 2010 and it broke the database so that I was unable to open it in Access 2007. The way I fixed it was to get him to remove the incompatible features and then import the objects into a new 2007 database. "Require Variable Declaration" is ON in both databases however the module I am testing with doesn't have Option Explicit as it predates me changing that setting. It fails at runtime in the sense the variable is Empty instead of containing the value. Compiles fine.

Comment: @enderland @ThomasGrandjean I have found that `myvalue = Me!FieldName` works but for some reason I used to be able to do `myvalue=FieldName` but that if I do that now the value is always `Empty`. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: If thats any help: When use a period, its "early binding", meaning that your variable is taken in account during compile. When you use ! Its "late binding" and it tells the compiler to ignore whats next, and your variable is evaluated at run time. I have no idea how to solve this issue other than address properly all your bound fields.

Comment: I've solved it now, thanks guys. I've posted the answer below.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution, I learned something today.

Answer (score 1):

Hah! I've solved it. I noticed at http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/recordsettype-property-HA001232788.aspx it says "NOTE Changing the RecordsetType property of an open form or report causes an automatic recreation of the recordset." so that is what I did. Opened the form in design mode, clicked the Form's RecordSource Type property and just set it to what it was already on, namely Dynaset. This seems to have been enough to trigger the recreation of the recordset and all of the fields in the underlying recordset are now available (rightly or wrongly) without using the `Me!` prefix and are also listed in Intellisense along with the forms controls. To be 100% sure I restored the database to before I made this change, tested it was still broken, made the change again and sure enough it resolved the problem.

Now as to the source of the problem I think it might well have been that the forms were imported BEFORE the Linked Tables on which they rely. I'm presuming this meant the form's recordsets weren't properly created when they were imported and making a trivial modification to the Recordset Type property is enough to trigger the recreation of the recordset. Note this is just conjecture at the moment.

Hopefully this information will help someone else who encounters the same problem.